# Dynamic inventory for Vagrant's Ansible provisioner?

Tags: ansible, vagrant

I am currently trying to write a dynamic inventory into the run portion of my Vagrant script, but am unable to enumerate things such as `vm_name` and `ip_address`. I know this is simply because I am trying to `f.write` the wrong lookup, unfortunately I do not know the variable I should be calling? You can see what I am attempting in the commented out section of my `Vagrantfile` towards the bottom.

```rb
Vagrant.configure(2) do | config |
  N = 2

  ANSIBLE_RAW_SSH_ARGS  = []
  ANSIBLE_INVENTORY_DIR = "provisioner/inventory"
  VAGRANT_VM_PROVIDER   = "virtualbox"

  (1..N-1).each do | machine_id |
    ANSIBLE_RAW_SSH_ARGS << "-o IdentityFile=.vagrant/machines/machine#{machine_id}/#{VAGRANT_VM_PROVIDER}/private_key"
  end

  (1..N).each do | machine_id |
    config.vm.define "machine#{machine_id}" do | machine |

      machine.vm.box      = "ubuntu/trusty64"
      machine.vm.hostname = "machine#{machine_id}"

      machine.vm.network "private_network",
        ip: "192.168.77.#{10+machine_id-1}"

      # only execute once the Ansible provisioner, when all the machines are up and ready.
      if machine_id == N
        machine.vm.provision :ansible do | ansible |
          # Disable default limit to connect to all the machines
          ansible.limit           = "all"
          ansible.playbook        = "provisioner/test.yml"
          ansible.inventory_path  = "#{ANSIBLE_INVENTORY_DIR}/vagrant"
          ansible.verbose         = "-v"

          ansible.raw_ssh_args    = ANSIBLE_RAW_SSH_ARGS
        end
        # dynamically create the Ansible inventory file
        Dir.mkdir(ANSIBLE_INVENTORY_DIR) unless Dir.exist?(ANSIBLE_INVENTORY_DIR)
        # File.open("#{ANSIBLE_INVENTORY_DIR}/vagrant" ,'w') do | f |
        #   f.write "[#{machine_id['vm_name']}]\n"
        #   f.write "#{machine_id['ip_address']}\n"
        # end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

*test.yml* if anyone cares

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - command: hostname -f
```

Comment: not familiar with vagrant, are you trying to create this file using jinja templating engine of ansible? if yes, i dont see the task, or the variables anywhere that you expect to replace the `vm_name` or `ip_address` in the file you provided.

Comment: @ilias-sp this has nothing to do with Jinja, they should theoretically be baked in variables from Vagrant

Comment: i see. then i guess the answer you are seeking is not ansible-related, but its in Vagrant's domain to be replaced. good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works even though it's not super pretty

```rb
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do | config |
  N = 3

  ANSIBLE_RAW_SSH_ARGS  = []
  ANSIBLE_INVENTORY_DIR = "provisioner/inventory"

  VAGRANT_VM_PROVIDER   = "virtualbox"

  (N-1..N).each do | machine_id |
    ANSIBLE_RAW_SSH_ARGS << "-o IdentityFile=.vagrant/machines/machine#{machine_id}/#{VAGRANT_VM_PROVIDER}/private_key"
  end

  # ensure directory exists
  Dir.mkdir(ANSIBLE_INVENTORY_DIR) unless Dir.exist?(ANSIBLE_INVENTORY_DIR)

  # dynamically create the Ansible inventory file
  File.open("#{ANSIBLE_INVENTORY_DIR}/hosts" ,'w') do | f |
    f.write "[all]\n"
    (N-1..N).each do | machine_id |
      f.write "192.168.77.#{10+machine_id-1}\n"
    end
    f.write "\n"
  end


  (1..N).each do | machine_id |
    config.vm.define "machine#{machine_id}" do | machine |
      machine.vm.box      = "ubuntu/trusty64"
      machine.vm.hostname = "machine#{machine_id}"

      machine.vm.network "private_network",
        ip: "192.168.77.#{10+machine_id-1}"

      # only execute once the Ansible provisioner, when all the machines are up and ready.
      if machine_id != 1

        # dynamically create individual Ansible entries
        File.open("#{ANSIBLE_INVENTORY_DIR}/hosts" ,'a') do | f |
          f.write "[machine#{machine_id}]\n"
          f.write "192.168.77.#{10+machine_id-1}\n"
          f.write "\n"
        end

        machine.vm.provision :ansible do | ansible |

          # Disable default limit to connect to all the machines
          ansible.limit           = "all"
          ansible.playbook        = "provisioner/test.yml"
          ansible.inventory_path  = "#{ANSIBLE_INVENTORY_DIR}/hosts"
          ansible.verbose         = "-v"
          ansible.raw_ssh_args    = ANSIBLE_RAW_SSH_ARGS
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Which gives me a dynamic hosts file of

```
[all]
192.168.77.11
192.168.77.12

[machine2]
192.168.77.11

[machine3]
192.168.77.12
```

Unfortunately it looks like i get a bad run, but i think this is due to a race condition where I am adding `machine3` prior to it being in service

```sh
...

machine2: Running ansible-playbook...
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR=true ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=false ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS='-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o IdentityFile=/Users/ehime/Repositories/Corporations/ByDeluxe/terraform-ansible/.vagrant/machines/machine2/virtualbox/private_key -o IdentityFile=.vagrant/machines/machine2/virtualbox/private_key -o IdentityFile=.vagrant/machines/machine3/virtualbox/private_key -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s' ansible-playbook --connection=ssh --timeout=30 --extra-vars=ansible_user\=\'vagrant\' --limit="all" --inventory-file=provisioner/inventory/hosts -v provisioner/test.yml
[WARNING]: log file at /var/log/ansible.log is not writeable and we cannot create it, aborting

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [command] *****************************************************************
changed: [192.168.77.11] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["hostname", "-f"], "delta": "0:00:00.003067", "end": "2018-06-06 00:06:19.628683", "rc": 0, "start": "2018-06-06 00:06:19.625616", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "machine2", "stdout_lines": ["machine2"]}
fatal: [192.168.77.12]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 192.168.77.12 port 22: Operation timed out\r\n", "unreachable": true}
to retry, use: --limit @/Users/ehime/Repositories/Corporations/ByDeluxe/terraform-ansible/provisioner/test.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.168.77.11              : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
192.168.77.12              : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

`vagrant status`

```
bash-4.4$ vagrant status
Current machine states:

machine1                  running (virtualbox)
machine2                  running (virtualbox)
machine3                  not created (virtualbox)
```